# Update Tabhost tab content

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost to which I dynamically add tabs.  When I add a new tab I create an intent to launch an activity as the content and add my data to the intent using putExtra.

This works fine when I create the tabs but my problem is updating the data in existing tabs.  My main activity periodically updates and I need to pass the data into the various tabs.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you need dynamically tabs?

Comment: I am polling a web page and using the tabs to reflect the structure of the page.  The tabs themselves change infrequently but the data contained within them changes often.  I've got the dynamic tabs working, but not the dynamic content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update current tab when you change the tab,
define each tab as an activity and when you want to update that just call update method of that activity:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
              ((yourTabActivity) getCurrentActivity()).yourUpdateMethod();
        }
  }
```